# PHP and HTML CSS TAGS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Below is my code, as i try to add html / css tags my page errors. I am using wordpress

```
<?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('lyrics') ):
    // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('lyrics') ) : the_row();
            // display a sub field value
            the_sub_field('lyric_title'); 

            // display a sub field value
            the_sub_field('lyrics_text');
        endwhile;
    else :
        // no rows found
    endif;
?>
```

I cannot figure out to:

1. how to add a div around each repeat for styling
2. Add a h3 to the_sub_field('lyric_title');
3. Add a p with a class to the_sub_field('lyrics_text');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because HTML does not go into PHP. You have two options.

1) Break up the php tags

```
<?php if( have_rows('lyrics') ): ?>
  <?php while ( have_rows('lyrics') ) : the_row(); ?>  
    <div class="">
      <?php  the_sub_field('lyric_title');  ?>  
      <?php the_sub_field('lyrics_text'); ?>  
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>  
<?php else : ?>  
  <div class="">
    Text
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

2) Echo the HTML

```
<?php
if( have_rows('lyrics') ) :
  while ( have_rows('lyrics') ) : the_row();
    echo "<div class=''>";
     the_sub_field('lyric_title'); 
     the_sub_field('lyrics_text');
    echo "</div>";
  endwhile;
else :
  echo "<div class=''>";
  echo "Text";
  echo "</div>";
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

// check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('lyrics') ):

// loop through the rows of data
  while ( have_rows('lyrics') ) : 
?>
<div>
  <?php the_row(); ?>

  // display a sub field value
  <h3> 
    <?php the_sub_field('lyric_title'); ?>
  </h3>
// display a sub field value
  <p class="class">
    the_sub_field('lyrics_text');
  </p>
</div>
endwhile;

else :

// no rows found

endif;

?>
```

You can very easly combine PHP with HTML within your Wordpress template like this. Just be sure to keep it readable.

Answer (score 0):

inside PHP markers, use echo command to print HTML:

```
echo '<div class="enclosed">';
while ( have_rows('lyrics') ) : the_row();
echo '</div>';
```

or you can close php code, write tag as is and open php code again:

```
//PHP code before
?>
<div class="enclosed">
<?php
while ( have_rows('lyrics') ) : the_row();
?>
</div>
<?php
//PHP code continues here
```